# Evaluating integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I come across a problem, which is to evaluate: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\,dx$$
My attempt so far is:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\,dx 
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\frac{2\tan(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}}\,dx\\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}{2+2\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})-2\tan(\frac{x}{2})}\,dx\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\frac{1}{2} \sec^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})-\tan(\frac{x}{2})}\,dx\end{align}$$
I'm wondering whether I'm in the right direction and how can I proceed?

Comment: [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) **Second example: a definite integral** goes through a very similar example step-by-step, otherwise I just notice that you could maybe try regular substitution $u=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, $du = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$ being careful with limits of course.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
& \frac 1 2 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac 1 {1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})-\tan(\frac{x}{2})} \big(\sec^2\tfrac x 2 \,dx\big) \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 2 \int_\text{?}^\text{?} \frac 1 {1+u^2 - u} \, du
\end{align}$$

Comment: The bounds of integration may take a bit of thought. And notice that $$ u^2-u+1 = \big( u-\tfrac 1 2\big)^2 + \tfrac 3 4, $$ and the antiderivative of this is an arctangent function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that because of periodicity, $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}.$

If you let $u = \tan\tfrac x2$ so that $\sin x= \dfrac{2u}{1+u^2}$ and $du = \dfrac{2\,du}{1+u^2},$ then as $x$ goes from $-\pi$ to $+\pi,$ $u$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty.$

\begin{align}
& \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \frac 1 {1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})-\tan(\frac{x}{2})} \big(\tfrac 1 2\sec^2\tfrac x 2 \,dx\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {1+u^2 - u} \, du \\[12pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {(u-\frac 1 2 )^2 + \frac 3 4} \, du \quad \left( \begin{array}{c} \text{This is complet-} \\ \text{ing the square.} \end{array} \right)\\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 4 3 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\left( \frac{2u-1}{\sqrt3} \right)^2 + 1} \, du \quad \left( \begin{array}{c} \text{Here we multiplied the} \\ \text{top and bottom by }4/3. \end{array} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 2 {\sqrt3}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\left( \frac{2u-1}{\sqrt3} \right)^2+1} \left( \tfrac 2 {\sqrt3} \, du \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 2 {\sqrt3} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {w^2+1} \, dw = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the bounds. But why do you put $\frac{1}{2}$ out of the integral sign considering the derivative of $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ is $\frac{1}{2}\sec^2(\frac{x}{2})$?

Comment: @dyluns : My attention was elsewhere at the time. (I'm accustomed to doing the tangent half-angle substitution by doing just what I said in the second paragraph above rather than by the way you did it.)  I've fixed this. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, the answer is doubled now, and the right one, it was the reason for posting mine. Well done, such answers propagate in an excellent way into the schools, not only for the didactical part +1

Answer (score 3):

Just for diversity, here is the solution involving complex analysis, which is always a good weapon when integrating rational functions of trigonometric functions. Let $z$ be
$$ z= e^{ix}\ ,$$
so *formally* $dz=i\; e^{ix}\; dx=iz\; dx$, so that we replace $dx$ by $\frac 1i\cdot\frac{dz}z$, and $\sin x=\frac 1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ (Euler) by $\frac 1{2i}\left(z-\frac 1z\right)$. So the integral $J$ (notation) to be computed on $[0,2\pi]$, becomes an integral on the unit circle $C$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\; dx
\\
&=
\int_C\frac 1{2-\frac 1{2i}\left(z-\frac 1z\right)}\; \frac 1i\cdot\frac {dz}z
=
\int_C\frac 1{2iz-\frac 12(z^2-1)}\; dz
=
-2
\int_C\frac 1{z^2-4iz-1}\; dz
\\[2mm]
&\qquad\ldots\text{ and the poles are in $2i\pm\sqrt{-4+1}=i(2\pm\sqrt 3)$,}
\\
&\qquad\ldots\text{ and only $i(2-\sqrt 3)$ contributes, the only pole inside $C$,}
\\[2mm]
&=-2\cdot 2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Residue}_{z=i(2-\sqrt 3)}
\frac 1{(z-i(2+\sqrt 3))(z-i(2-\sqrt 3))}
\\
&=-2\cdot 2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Value}_{z=i(2-\sqrt 3)}
\frac 1{(z-i(2+\sqrt 3))}
\\
&=-2\cdot 2\pi i\cdot
\frac 1{i(2-\sqrt 3)-i(2+\sqrt 3)}
=-2\cdot 2\pi i\cdot\frac 1{-2i\sqrt 3}
=2\pi \cdot\frac 1{\sqrt 3}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Numerical check using `pari/gp`:

```
gp > intnum(x=0, 2*Pi, 1/(2 - sin(x)))
%129 = 3.6275987284684357011881565152843114645681324961854811511397698707762463622527078
gp > 2*Pi/sqrt(3)
%130 = 3.6275987284684357011881565152843114645681324961854811511397698707762463622527078
```

Comment: @michael-hardy oh, the ldots... ok, i will edit like that in the future...

Comment: I studied complex analysis on my own about 20 years ago and don't remember any of it. Congratulations on the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the step-by-step process I mentioned in the link to deal with the discontinuity at $x=\pi$.

Using Weierstrass substitution $t = \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, where $-\pi < x < \pi$ or $\pi < x < 3\pi$, then $\sin(x) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, $dx = \frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$, there is a discontinuity at $x=\pi$ that needs to be taken into account, first you find the indefinite integral and then evaluate the limits of the endpoints of the improper integrals. First split the integral:

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\:dx = \int\limits_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\:dx +\int\limits_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\:dx.$$

Then evaluate the indefinite integral. Since $\frac{1}{2-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}= \frac{1+t^2}{2(t^2-t+1)}$, $\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\:dx = \frac{1}{t^2-t+1}\:dt$, hence

$$\int\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\:dx = \int\frac{1}{t^2-t+1}\:dt,$$

substituting $t = s + \frac{1}{2}$ to get rid of the $-t$, then $dt=ds$, and $$\int\frac{1}{t^2-t+1}\:dt  = \int\frac{1}{s^2 +\frac{3}{4}}\:ds = \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\int\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2s}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+1}\:\frac{2}{\sqrt3}ds =\\ \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\int\frac{1}{u^2+1}\:du = \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan(u) $$

with $u =\frac{2s}{\sqrt3}$ and the answer of the indefinite integral is := $\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1}{\sqrt3}\right)$

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\:dx +\int\limits_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2-\sin(x)}\:dx = \\\lim_{b\rightarrow\pi^{-}}\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1}{\sqrt3}\right)\Biggr|_0^b + \lim_{b\rightarrow\pi^{+}}\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1}{\sqrt3}\right)\Biggr|_b^{2\pi} = \\ \lim_{b\rightarrow\pi^{-}}\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\tan\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)-1}{\sqrt3}\right) - \lim_{b\rightarrow\pi^{+}}\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\tan\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)-1}{\sqrt3}\right) - \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}\right) + \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}\right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2} - \left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + 0 = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}$$

since you can't evaluate at $\pi$.